# ANTLRv4: non-greedy rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm reading the definite ANTLR4 reference and have a question regarding one of the examples (p. 76):

```
STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"';
fragment 
ESC: '\\"' | '\\\\' ;
```

The rule matches a typical C++ string - a char sequence included in `""`, which can contain `\"` too.

In my expectation, the rule `STRING` should match the smallest string possible because of the non-greedy construct. So if it sees a `\"` it would map `\` to `.` and `"` to `"` at the end of the rule, since this would result in the smallest string possible. Instead of this, a `\"` is mapped to `ESC`. I have an understanding problem, since it is not what I expected.

What exactly happens here? Is it like this, that a separated DFA matches `(ESC|.)` first, and another DFA matches `STRING` using the already matched string of the `(ESC|.)` construct? I have to admit I haven't read the book to the end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ANTLR 4 lexers normally operate with longest-match-wins behavior, without any regard for the order in which alternatives appear in the grammar. If two lexer *rules* match the same longest input sequence, only then is the relative order of those rules compared to determine how the token type is assigned.

The behavior within a rule changes as soon as the lexer reaches a non-greedy optional or closure. From that moment forward *to the end of the rule*, all alternatives within that rule will be treated as ordered, and the path with the lowest alternative wins. This seemingly strange behavior is actually responsible for the non-greedy handling due to [the way we order alternatives in the underlying ATN representation](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/atn/ATNState.html). When the lexer is in this mode and reaches the block `(ESC|.)`, the ordering constraint requires it use `ESC` if possible.

Comment: So I take it that if the rule was `STRING: '"' (.|ESC)*? '"';` (with the `.` alternative before the `ESC` alternative), then what @Andy said would indeed happen? 
> So if it sees a `\"` it would map `\ ` to `.` and `"` to `"` at the end of the rule