# ANTLR4 rules priority

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to get a simple grammar to work using ANTLR4. Basically a list of keywords separated by `;` that can be negated using `Not`. Something like this, for example:

```
Not negative keyword;positive
```

I wrote the following grammar:

```
grammar input;

input               : clauses;
keyword             : NOT? WORD;
clauses             : keyword (SEPARATOR clauses)?;

fragment N          : ('N'|'n') ;
fragment O          : ('O'|'o') ;
fragment T          : ('T'|'t') ;
fragment SPACE      : ' ' ;

SEPARATOR           : ';';
NOT                 : N O T SPACE;
WORD                : ~[;]+;
```

My issue is that in the `keyword` rule, `WORD` seems to have more priority than `NOT`. `Not something` is recognized as the `Not something` word instead of a negated `something`.

For instance, the parse tree I get is this

[image: this].

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this

[image: like this]

How can you give an expression more priority over another on ANTLR4? Any tip on fixing this?

Please note that while this grammar is very simple and ANTLR4 can seem unecessary here, the true grammar I want to make is more complex and I have just simplified it here to demonstrate my issue.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANTLRv4: non-greedy rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787242/antlrv4-non-greedy-rules)

Comment: Note that `~[';']` is equivalent to `~[';]` and matches any character other than `'` or `;` (repeating a character in a character class does nothing). I assume you want just `~[;]` or `~';'` (both of which mean "any character other than `;`").

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I fixed it on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no explicit whitespace rule and you include whitespaces in your WORD rule. Yet you want words separated by whitespaces. That cannot work. Don't include whitespaces in words (that's against the usual meaning of a word anyway). Instead specify exactly what a word is really (usually a combination of letters and digits, not led by a letter). Additionally, I would restructure the grammar such that `positive` and `negative` are not part of `keyword`, but separate entitites. Here I defined them as own keywords, but if that is not what you want replace them with just `WORD`:

```
grammar input;

input               : clauses EOF;
keyword             : NOT? (POSITIVE | NEGATIVE) WORD?;
clauses             : keyword (SEPARATOR keyword)*;

fragment A: [aA];
fragment B: [bB];
fragment C: [cC];
fragment D: [dD];
fragment E: [eE];
fragment F: [fF];
fragment G: [gG];
fragment H: [hH];
fragment I: [iI];
fragment J: [jJ];
fragment K: [kK];
fragment L: [lL];
fragment M: [mM];
fragment N: [nN];
fragment O: [oO];
fragment P: [pP];
fragment Q: [qQ];
fragment R: [rR];
fragment S: [sS];
fragment T: [tT];
fragment U: [uU];
fragment V: [vV];
fragment W: [wW];
fragment X: [xX];
fragment Y: [yY];
fragment Z: [zZ];

SEPARATOR : ';';
NOT       : N O T;
POSITIVE  : P O S I T I V E;
NEGATIVE  : N E G A T I V E;

fragment LETTER: DIGIT | LETTER_NO_DIGIT;
fragment LETTER_NO_DIGIT: [a-zA-Z_$\u0080-\uffff];
WORD: LETTER_NO_DIGIT LETTER*;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\f\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
fragment DIGIT:    [0-9];
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
```

which gives you this parse tree for your input:

[image]